# AB-testing and content management in urbanairship push notifications

Tags: urbanairship.com

https://www.urbanairship.com/products/pricing
From the pricing there is available in the comprehensive package offering something called the "message center". In combination with the AB-testing does this mean there is some functionality similar to Mailchimp?

Ideally we are looking for a push notification system that can send push notifications with a content id... the content then be content managed y the marketing dept.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a different feature that Urban Airship provides, [Message Personalization](http://docs.urbanairship.com/whats-new/july-2016-release.html#message-personalization); this allows you to define push notifications with (optional) merge fields to a pre-defined template which can be updated by the marketing department.

Just for completeness, the other features you list above solve different problems:

- A/B testing is multivariate testing; you can define multiple messages to send to percentages of your audience, and see which one performs better
- [Message Center](http://docs.urbanairship.com/topic-guides/index.html#message-center) is an in-application "inbox" to which you can send messages